Why can't I use Selenium and chromedriver?
I use Selenium and ChromeDriver in Python to scrape a website but every time I get the same error that I can't resolve on fairly specific points (GetHandleverifier, BaseThreadInitThunk, etc.).
I've installed ChromeDriver (the right one) and the path is correct too
You can see my code and my error below:
Code :
    import os
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import filedialog
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

    chromedriver_path = "chromedriver.exe"

    def ask_directory():
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()  # Masquer la fenêtre principale de Tkinter
        folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
        return folder_selected

    download_directory = ask_directory()
    if not download_directory:
        print("Aucun dossier sélectionné, arrêt du programme.")
        exit()

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1024,768')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)


    try:
    
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
        # Accéder à la page de connexion
        driver.get('https://plugintheme.net/my-account/')

Error :
    Erreur : Message: 
    Stacktrace:
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00B30F03+27667]
            (No symbol) [0x00AC6C04]
            (No symbol) [0x009C1AFF]
            (No symbol) [0x00A02BFE]
            (No symbol) [0x00A02CDB]
            (No symbol) [0x00A3EC22]
            (No symbol) [0x00A23974]
            (No symbol) [0x00A3CAC7]
            (No symbol) [0x00A236C6]
            (No symbol) [0x009F74D1]
            (No symbol) [0x009F804D]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00DE3D83+2857619]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00E37EED+3202045]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00BB4704+566292]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00BBB8FC+595468]
            (No symbol) [0x00ACF9F4]
            (No symbol) [0x00ACC708]
            (No symbol) [0x00ACC8A7]
            (No symbol) [0x00ABE79E]
            BaseThreadInitThunk [0x754F7BA9+25]
            RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x7740C10B+107]
            RtlClearBits [0x7740C08F+191]

I've tried updating the various libraries used, updating "undetected-chromedriver", installing the versions of chromedriver linked to my current version of Chrome.
I think the problem is with the driver but I can't be sure.

Update WebDriver Manager
Ensure that webdriver-manager is up to date. You can update it using pip:
pip install --upgrade webdriver-manager

Example Code with Additional Logging
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import logging

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

chromedriver_path = "chromedriver.exe"

def ask_directory():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()  # Masquer la fenêtre principale de Tkinter
    folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
    return folder_selected

download_directory = ask_directory()
if not download_directory:
    print("Aucun dossier sélectionné, arrêt du programme.")
    exit()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1024,768')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')

try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    logger.info("ChromeDriver successfully started.")

    # Accéder à la page de connexion
    driver.get('https://plugintheme.net/my-account/')
    logger.info("Navigated to https://plugintheme.net/my-account/")

except Exception as e:
    logger.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")
finally:
    if driver:
        driver.quit()
        logger.info("ChromeDriver session ended.")


I updated it and still get the same error

Do you have your chromedriver.exe in the same file as your script?
Because chromedriver_path = "chromedriver.exe" suggests that it is.
Maybe you can try to find your chromedriver.exe file first
In order to do that, this screenshot shows the path of your chromedriver depending on your OS :

Try to replace the value of chromedriver_path by that path.

My driver is in the same folder
